# Why can't Js load image files from my web service directory?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, tomcat, jersey

I have a domain `www.foo.com` and wish to host a JAX-RS/Maven/Jersey web service there. Currently, I'm packaging the Java code into a .war file and deploying it on an Apache Tomcat 8.0 web server for testing on my local machine.

In `/apache8/webapps/ROOT/index.html` (`localhost:8080/`) I have script tags within which an XMLHttpRequest object makes a get request to `localhost:8080/apiIndex/webapi/resource` - which searches a resource folder in my web service directory that contains 150 or so images. The the full path names to those images are returned to my Js code, and that Js code attempts to create images out of them to be drawn to a canvas.

The problem is, I'm getting a network error saying that Js can't find/load the images.

How do I map an index.html file to my domain from within my web service directory, so that when I forward requests from my domain to port 8080 of my server I can access those images from code within my web service package? Is this the reason the Js code in the tomcat webapps folder can't load the images from my API's src/java/resources folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: `/apache8/webapps/index.html` does not sound like something that's mapped to `localhost:8080`. I'd rather expect the / (root) webapplication to be deployed under `/apache8/webapps/ROOT` (and the index.html file within that folder).

I'm assuming that your web application with the images is deployed under /apache8/webapps/apiIndex. If that generates, as you say "the full path names" of your images, that can't be found: What are those full path names, and where do you expect them to be? Do you get 404 error codes or something else - like 500? Please post URLs and your expected places in the folder.

(this is posted as an answer instead of a comment because I hope that the initial description help you find the root of your problem yourself, while the second part is effectively asking for more information)

Edit: Following your comment: IMHO your webservice should rather return a http or https reference to an image, rather than a file reference. If anything else, you might need to prefix it with `file:///home/...` in order for the browser to consider getting it. However, if your browser shows a http document, it might not even cross that domain and embed local file resources for security reasons: Why would any webserver reference material on your local disk?

Have your images somewhere where you can reference them through http and the problem should be solved.

Comment: A GET request to `localhost:8080/apiIndex/webapi/resource` returns a JSON object with props like: `/home/novice/workspace/app/src/java/resources/images/image01.jpg`. This is the absolute path name to the location of the image on my server.